# How do I fix Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError while changing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite, sequel

In the process of transition from sqlite to postgresql, I use this command `taps server SQLite://db/development.sqlite3 jey 291298`, but then the following problem appears. Maybe something is wrong with Gemfile. My version of rails is 5.1.6.

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.8.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:105:in `initialize': SQLite3::CantOpenException: unable to open database file (Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.8.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:105:in `new'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.8.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:105:in `connect'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.8.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:126:in `make_new'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.8.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:192:in `assign_connection'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.8.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:133:in `acquire'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.8.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:90:in `hold'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.8.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:264:in `synchronize'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.8.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:279:in `test_connection'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.8.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:58:in `connect'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.8.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:116:in `connect'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/db_session.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/server.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/cli.rb:61:in `server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/cli.rb:27:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/taps-0.3.24/bin/taps:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/taps:22:in `load'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/taps:22:in `<main>'
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'whenever', require: false
gem 'bcrypt', platforms: :ruby
gem 'cancan'
gem 'devise' 
gem 'rubocop', require: false
gem 'ransack'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'nested_form'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'state_machine'
gem 'ruby-graphviz', :require => 'graphviz'
gem 'stateful_enum'
gem 'hpricot'
gem 'highline'
gem "slim-rails"  
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6'
gem 'pg'
gem 'resque'
gem 'sinatra', '~> 2.0.0.beta2'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2' 
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bullet', group: 'development'
```

**Some fragments from Gemfile.lock:**

```
sequel (5.8.0)
sinatra (2.0.1)
  mustermann (~> 1.0)
  rack (~> 2.0)
  rack-protection (= 2.0.1)
  tilt (~> 2.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the error being `SQLite3::CantOpenException: unable to open database file`, the issue is that the `ruby-sqlite3` driver cannot open the database file.  Try running `sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3` from the shell and see if you get the same or similar error.  If so, it could be the file doesn't exist or the user does not have access to it.  If not, it could be an issue in the `ruby-sqlite3` driver.